# Data loader missing field, but data is present

Tags: data-loader

I exported an Account from one sandbox with the intention of inserting it into another (i.e. I am copying data between orgs). This is a simple CSV file with two lines: the first has the field names (header row), the second is the data for the Account.

When data loader attempts to load it, the record errors out because Name is missing. However, it is there in the fourth field, plain as day. When I select the CSV file, data loader shows the fields and Name is there.

Header:

```
"ID","ISDELETED","MASTERRECORDID","NAME",...
```

Data:

```
"","false","","Test Data",...
```

How do I resolve this error? Is it procedural on my part? Bug in data loader? Is there a better way of copying data between orgs?

Comment: it sounds like an issue with the csv file, have you verified that is properly formatted, perhaps using notepad++?

Comment: I did open it in Notepad++ but it does not validate anything. I also opened it in Excel to make sure the data is in the correct fields and is not mangled in any way, and it looks fine.

Comment: (1) is your Dataloader Map file (.sdl) correct in terms of mapping the proper column to account.name?  (2) What happens if you create the same data by hand (1 row) in excel and save as CSV - will that import without error?

Comment: Can you reduce the size of your CSV file to just the first record. If data loader can handle that then it is likely there is data in one of the rows causing an issue.

Comment: This is a single record: an Account in a two-line CSV file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an [RTFM moment](http://na1.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_data_loader.pdf). Despite the fields existing in the CSV file, that does not actually map them into the org's data. It is possible that the two orgs have slightly different data layouts, and Data Loader cannot know that.

In this case the layouts were the same, so I told it to auto-detect the field mapping and it easily figured it out (the field names are identical between these two orgs).

Thanks to @crop1645 and @varum guruvugari for the hints that made me go back and comb through the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Please TRY to use jitterBit data loader just as an alternative and if it still errors out then  it confirms that there is something wrong with the file or the mapping file.

use the same data to create via UI, so it confirms whether the data in the file/mapping file is correct or NOT.

If the data load using JitterBit loader works then it is not a bug with salesforce.